# Change the Label's foreground colour on MouseOver WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I have the following problem: I have a `Button`, which has a `StackPanel` inside it, with a `ContentControl` and a `Label` within the `StackPanel`, and I've set the button's properties `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed` to change the button's colour when the action happen. But, I would like to invert the label's colour when the mouse is over the button.

This is my button's code: (because I think my description is not clear enough):

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource OnMouseOver}" ToolTip="Release" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Release}"/>
        <Label Content="Release" Foreground="#457345" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

This is how I changed the button's properties when the button is pressed and when the mouse is over the button:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="OnMouseOver">
    <Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent">
        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#A1CCA1"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#AFD8AF"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

For the record, I've tried to do something like `ControlTemplate` for my label, but it didn't work, and my label just vanished when I did.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="OnMouseOver">
<Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent">       
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl />
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="Release" Foreground="#457345" />
        </StackPanel>
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#A1CCA1"/> 
         <Setter TargetName="label" Property="Foreground" Value="#AFD8AF"/>     
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#AFD8AF"/>
         <Setter TargetName="label" Property="Foreground" Value="#A1CCA1"/> 
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

```
<Button x:Name="button" Template="{StaticResource OnMouseOver}" ToolTip="Release" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="235,0,127,143" >

    </Button>
```